# I use pandas to compute some data,and want to process dataframe from the second row,not the first row,how to do?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

df=["TodayTotalAmount"] = df.apply(lambda x: _computeTodayTotalAmount(x['OpeningMethods'],startupCapital,x['TodayTotalAmount'],x['TodayTotalAmount'].shift(1)), axis=1)

```
    def _computeTodayTotalAmount(OpeningMethods,startupCapital,todayOpeningMagnification ,yesterdayOpeningMagnification):
       if todayOpeningMagnification.isnull():
           todayOpeningMagnification = startupCapital
       else:
          if OpeningMethods == "Long":
              return todayOpeningMagnification-yesterdayOpeningMagnification
          elif OpeningMethods == "Short" :
              return -(todayOpeningMagnification-yesterdayOpeningMagnification)
          else:
              return 0
```

Comment: read notice : [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Your question should definitely need some clarification, but if I understand it well, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'OpeningMethods': ['Long', 'Short', 'Long', 'Short'],
    'TodayTotalAmount': [100, 200, 300, 400],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
startupCapital = 1000  

df['YesterdayTotalAmount'] = df['TodayTotalAmount'].shift(1)

def _computeTodayTotalAmount(OpeningMethods, startupCapital, todayTotalAmount, yesterdayTotalAmount):
    if pd.isnull(yesterdayTotalAmount):
        return startupCapital 
    else:
        if OpeningMethods == "Long":
            return todayTotalAmount - yesterdayTotalAmount
        elif OpeningMethods == "Short":
            return -(todayTotalAmount - yesterdayTotalAmount)
        else:
            return 0

df["TodayTotalAmount"] = df.apply(lambda x: _computeTodayTotalAmount(x['OpeningMethods'], startupCapital, x['TodayTotalAmount'], x['YesterdayTotalAmount']), axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
  OpeningMethods  TodayTotalAmount  YesterdayTotalAmount
0           Long            1000.0                   NaN
1          Short            -100.0                 100.0
2           Long             100.0                 200.0
3          Short            -100.0                 300.0
```